# Aligned equation in the same line with the text in LyX

Tags: align

I want to add an aligned equation (one of `ctrl`+`shift`+`m`), but in the same line as the text before.

Is it possible, and how do I do it in LyX (not LaTeX)?

---

Edit:

An example from the book we use in university:

[image]

Comment: LyX uses LaTeX underneath... I'd say that this makes no sense at all to mix text and displayed math. Perhaps you can explain in more detail exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I added a picture. Hope you can see it.